# MYSQL - Error 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MSQL Version

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Al intentar cargar datos en una tabla me da dicho error.

> Error Code 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

La función que uso es:

> load data local infile 'C:\Users\xSyn\Archivo.csv'

He estado buscando por internet y algunos dicen que tengo que ejecutar el comando

> local-infile=1

Pero no sé cómo. En mi propio script de MySQL me da error y ya no sé qué hacer.

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: No sé mucho de `mysql`, pero `local-infile=1` parece una opción de un fichero de configuración.

Comment: Revisa estas dos entradas. Te pueden ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/enabling-load-data-local-infile-in-mysql

Comment: @PAGANA pero en ambos datos me pide "start up mysql with this" y unos comandos. ¿Desde dónde puedo lanzar esos comandos?

Comment: Si especificaras en qué plataforma y versión de mysql  estás trabajando sería más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

Suponiendo que el sistema operativo es Windows (veo el parámetro "`C:\Users\xSyn...`") y que el comando "`load data local infile`..." se ejecuta desde línea de comandos ("*mi propio script de MySQL*") creo que hay dos maneras principales de "setear" el valor de local-infile.

La primera es desde mysql "prompt":

1) Ir a carpeta de mysql.exe. En mi caso se trata de MySQL 8 y la carpeta es `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` pero esto depende de release:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) Comprobar es estado de local_infile: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';`

3) `SET GLOBAL local_infile='ON';`

4) Otra vez `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` para ver si el parámetro ha cambiado.´
Últimos tres pasos estan en la captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Otra manera (pero no estoy seguro sobre el valor exacto del parámetro) sería setearlo desde Servicios de Windows.

1) Ir a Panel de control -> Herramientas administrativas -> Servicios

2) Encotrar MySQL. El mío es MySQL80 pero esto depende de la release. Parar el servicio con "Detener".

3) Abrir Propiedades con el botón derecho de ratón.

4) No estoy seguro que hay que poner exactamente en el campo "`Parámetros de inicio`", si va guion, guion bajo, ON, 1, etc. pero algo parecido debería funcionar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5) `Inciar` el servicio.

Comment: y como la haria en linux?

Comment: Si puedes conectarte a mysql, sería lo mismo... Comprobar con mysql> show global variables like 'local%';
Entonces, mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile='ON';

Comment: He intentado jugar con los parámetros de línea de comandos del "daemon" mysqld, pero, sinceramente, no he conseguido cambiar el valor.
En mi versión de Linux: `$mysqld --local-infile start`
Resulta que por defecto el valor es 'ON' y solo he podido cambiarlo con `SET GLOBAL...` 
El Help (`mysqld --verbose --help`) lo explica que valor se revierte a "OFF" con --skip-local-infile, pero a mí siempre me dejaba el valor "ON" para el cliente: --`local-infile -  Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (Defaults to on; use --skip-local-infile to disable.)`

Comment: En teoría, este valor debería setearse desde my.cnf (o my.ini), en Linux sería editando el fichero p.ej. /etc/my.cnf y añadiendo la línea `local_infile=ON`.
Pero, parece que esto no es siempre posible para todas las versiones de Linux. Ver, por ejemplo, este link en inglés: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/enabling-load-data-local-infile-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

primero hay que ingresar con:

mysql --local_infile=1 -u root -p

ya adentro escribe

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
si esta en OFF, encender con

SET GLOBAL local_infile='ON';

y listo....